# Unable to Add Additional Fields in Aspnetuser table

Tags: asp.net-core, ef-code-first, asp.net-identity

I have created a custom fields and trying to insert the custom fields in aspnetusers tables, but the additional fiels data is not inserted. Below is the code i tried:

```
            var identityUser = new CreateUser
            {

                Email = model.Email,
                UserName = model.Email,
                TenantId = obj.ToString(),
                IsAdmin= true


            };
            var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(identityUser, model.Password);
            var assignRole = await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(identityUser, "ADMIN");
```

**Class:**

```
    public class CreateUser:IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string OrganizationName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }

    public string TenantId { get; set; }
    public bool IsAdmin { get; set; }
}
```

DbContext:

```
  public class ApplicationDBContext:IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>
{

    public ApplicationDBContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {


    }

}
```

**StartUp**

```
            //Configure Entity Frameworkcore with SQL Server
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDBContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
        });
```

Is anything missing here, only the original fields gets updated while the added fields value is not inserted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here should be the CreateUser:

```
public class ApplicationDBContext : IdentityDbContext<CreateUser>
{

    public ApplicationDBContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {

    }

}
```

Startup.cs:

```
services.AddIdentity<CreateUser, IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
    .AddDefaultUI();
```

Dependency injection:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly UserManager<CreateUser> _userManager;

    public HomeController(UserManager<CreateUser> userManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
    }

    //...

}
```

The detail steps to customize could be found in [Customize the model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-3.1#custom-user-data) document .

Comment: You should replace IdentityUser with CreateUser in your startup ConfigureService, also use this CreateUser when dependency inject the userManager.

Comment: Error shows when i change to this: System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot create a DbSet for 'IdentityUser' because this type is not included in the model for the context